Which word can be used to describe either the beat or the subdivision?
Say I have a metronome that plays a sound on the beat and no sound on any of the subdivisions.
Say my goal is to clap my hands whenever the beat sound is played AND whenever I feel the subdivision(s) of my choice.
I'm looking for a word that can refer to either the beat or the subdivision. My best candidate so far is "unit of time." That is, instead of saying that my goal is to clap my hands on the beat and the subdivision(s) of my choice, I would say that my goal is to clap my hands on the units of time of my choice.
My other candidates are "time target" and "moment."
Still, I'm not happy with any of my candidates as they feel vague. It feels as if there is a better word to describe either the beat or the subdivision. Any suggestions?

You might get more useable answers by editing to say: Why do you want this word? I have a sinking feeling that you're designing an app and want to label something. If so, there is no reasonable solution IMO. But if you want to discuss this in ordinary language, your best bet is to mention the subdivisions directly: "The beat is quarters but I'm going to clap eighths."

@AndyBonner Yes, your feeling is correct. I'm trying to label a term in my app that refers to both the beat and the subdivision(s). This is for internal usage and is not for discussion in ordinary language. Writing "Beat or subdivision" all the time is tedious and gives me the sinking feeling there is a better word out there. Plus, it might improve my own vocabulary.

The description of this app isn't very clear. Or, if it is supposed to do something musical regarding rhythm, it is very incomplete. You said the beat subdivisions is "your choice?" Don't you mean the app user's choice? How do they choose? How will it be presented to the user for them to follow?

@PascalBergeron Well, if it's purely internal, of course you can use whatever you want. But it seems like you've left the possibilities so open—the only thing determining when you clap is "when you want to clap"—that it's becoming defined by just that, the clapping. It's not clear if all claps will always be equally spaced. If they are, I would speak of "subdivisions" even if some land on the beat. But one way or the other, I would speak of them programmatically as something like "clap points."

@MichaelCurtis My apologies. I did not want to bother people with endless details and tried to keep it a succinct (but complete) as possible. That being said, the answers given seem clear: there is no term for what I'm looking for, but the suggestions are good enough.

The most general term is "pulse", which can refer to any level of beat, subdivision, or "superdivision". However, that doesn't sound quite like what you're looking for.
When clapping a consistent subdivision, one would say "I'm clapping triplets/sextuplets/17-tuplets (etc.)", and it's understood that includes a clap on the beat itself.
Another way to say the same thing is just to call it a "subdivision", modified to describe the level of subdivision: clapping a subdivision of two, or three, or seven. "I'm going to clap on the beat with a duple/triple/septuple subdivision".
If you're clapping unequal subdivisions, the you would refer to this as "rhythm". "I'll be clapping on the beats plus a rhythm of my choosing."

If it's equal subdivision, maybe "subbeat"?  Otherwise, agree with @Aaron that "rhythm" is a good word.

'"pulse", which can refer to any level of beat, subdivision, or "superdivision"': I get the sense from some messages posted on this site that at least some use "pulse" more specifically, though without explanation or context I'd never know whether they mean "subdivision" or "superdivision."

The Wiki on Clave Theory uses the term "pulse" in most places to describe subbeats. Often, the word "stroke" is used. My reading of the article is that "pulse" refers to the location and "stroke" refers to the playing of something at that point.

Can we have a "subdivision of one" (that is, we only count the beat)?

@PascalBergeron Well, the point of "sub-" is that it's less than the primary division.

@PascalBergeron Chuck Norris can. :-) But, no, "subdivision", as Andy Bonner wrote, implies a smaller unit of time than the beat.

I think you are getting distracted from a pretty basic task by using the term "beat."
The term that should work for your task is simply: notes.
Beat is a very abstract concept. It is an instantaneous moment in time.
Beats are not performed. Notes are performed. Just because a series of notes are all on the beat does not mean beats are being performed. It is notes on the beat that are being performed.
You can select whatever note you want for beat length values. Which of those beat length notes is subdivided and what subdivision amount is optional, but the result will be more notes of shorted durations.
You didn't mention meter or measures in your task. I don't know if that is intentional, but let's continue with no other concepts like meter, measure, tempo, etc.
Example, a quarter note is set for the beat length, a series of 8 quarter notes is set, the second and fifth of those 8 are subdivided by two each using two eighth notes. As described, with minimal music information, it would look like this...

You will be clapping, performing those notes.
The way beat comes into the picture is a reference point for describing the rhythm of the notes:
Some of those notes are beat length in duration, but not all.
Some of those notes are on the beat others are not.
If meter and measure were part of the task, you could then give ordinals to the beats and measures. Ex, the pattern is in 4/4 meter, the length is two measures, quarter notes are on the beat, the 4th beat of measure 1 is subdivided by 2 into eighth notes, and the 2nd beat of measure 2 is subdivided by 4 into sixteenth notes. These are the basic terms that describe rhythm in music. This would seem to be the stuff you need for a rhythm clapping app.
Whatever way you end up encoding these "units of time" it will be de facto notation. However it is presented to the user, assuming it is first presented and then performed (how else would this app work?), that presentation will also be de facto notation. You are working with notes.

My answer is, there is no commonly understood word for the imaginary subdivision that's in your head and that you explicate by playing somewhere between metronome clicks or snare hits. Pulse feels the closest to me, and sub-beat the second closest, but they still leave possibility for misunderstanding.
First of all, the pulse or sub-beat rhythm is an idea in your mind or your perception, it does not have to exist as already explicated sound in a recording or other artifact.
Secondly, the pulse or sub-beat rhythm is not necessarily a mechanical grid of time divisions of equal length. There is of course the idea of swing which means that in-between pulses or sub-beats are delayed compared to an equal-length grid. And there are various other non-even rhythmic feels, styles or "grooves". This is why  I don't like any of the words that refer to some sort of "smallest time unit". There is no quantum-like smallest time unit in rhythm. Rhythm is a continuous spectrum of different feels.
EDIT. One word that's actually used for referring to the density of a pulse or sub-beat division, including various amounts of swing, is feel. For example "16th feel", "dotted 8th feel", "triplet feel", "straight 8th note feel". You can check this with internet search engines. :)
Wikipedia mentions "feel" at least here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_time "Groove" is mentioned as a potential synonym.
If I was making a music application where the user can select between these alternatives, I'd label it rhythmic feel.

I believe "tatum" is the exact concept you're seeking. It comes from the research community though and I've never heard it used in a rehearsal/professional setting.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatum_(music)
The word was coined to resemble "atom". It refers to the smallest cognitively meaningful unit of time in a musical context (i.e. not getting into microtiming which is more felt).
So, the OP could say "I will clap my hand on the tatum of my choice" - meaning it could be on the beat or a subdivison between the beat.
As others have noted, "subdivision" can be used equivalently (to include both the beat and the subdivisions falling between the beat) and is better-known.

Tatum seems to be the smallest interval between beats. Not just the same as pulse, but an interesting revelation.

Pulse or beat are often used synonymously.
But - what happens with say, 6/8? It could be (and often is) said to have 6 pulses and 2 beats.
To say, for each different pulse/beat, what you're doing, it's probably best to specify exactly the time signature you're using. Given beat 1 as the only guide, as you say, the ensuing bars could be divided however you wish. 1  2 3 4, 1 2 3, 1 2 3 4 5, and so on. So saying 'I'm counting in 4/4, 3/4, or 5/4' respectively, would suffice.

Not 'unit of time'.   Units of time are seconds or minutes, not beats or sub-beats.   Perhaps 'beats and sub-beats' is the best we've got?

My entrance is 4 beats after the rehearsal mark, I'm expressing a length of time with the unit "beat"

@Edward But the length of time between beats depends on the tempo.

@ElementsInSpace Sure, but it's still a unit of measure- at least as much as "percent" is- and it measures time...

@ElementsInSpace it's not unlike "glasses" as a unit of volume.  It's not standardized or invariable or even very precise, but it is still a unit of measure.

Your candidate words unit of time, time target and moment, suggest you are looking for something connected to time. What about tick?

I'll note that tick is already used to mean the smallest unit of time in MIDI.
